# jquery autocomplete: How to show suggestion list again?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

jquery, textbox with autocomplete, change event problem:

I have a textbox which is used to show some suggestion (doesnt matter what).
No problem at all, works well, but I have big problems to solve this:

1. the user enters some characters in the textbox, like "abcd".
2. the suggestion list is shown
3. the user leaves the textbox instead of selecting a suggestion. 
   Means the autocomplete textbox contains still the characters "abcd".

What I want:
The suggestion list for "abcd" should again shown when the user clicks again in the autocomplete textbox.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this on focus

```
$("input#searchField").focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete( "search" , this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input#myTextbox").focus(function() { 
    showSuggestions($("input#myTextbox").val()); 
});
```

Assuming you have a `showSuggestions` function which gets text as parameter to show the list of suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful answer, lol ... What a stupid answer - answers is like: Hey call method X() - assuming X() can call the suggestion list. ;-)

Comment: Lol, you wrote that showing suggestions is working for you. You only needed answer on how to do it while user clicks on textbox. I provided you exactly that answer (the part with `.focus()` and you call it stupid...

Answer (score 0):

show some codes so we can understand what exactly you're trying to do...
If you're using scripts running queries on a database to get the suggestions? then i think this should help because am using this to accomplish the same thing on my website.

```
var suggest = {
    url:'',
    search_form:'searchform',
    results_box:'',
    selected_result:undefined,
    had_focus:false,

    init:function() {
        if ( $('suggest_results') == undefined )
            return;

        suggest.results_box = $('suggest_box');
        suggest.results_box.hide();

        var s = $('s');
        s.setAttribute("autocomplete","off");
        s.setAttribute("placeholder","Search");
        s.onkeypress = suggest.noEnter;
        new Form.Element.Observer(s, 1.0, suggest.show_results);
        Event.observe(s, "keypress", suggest.handleKeypress, false);

        Event.observe(s, "blur", suggest.lostFocus, false);
        Event.observe(s, "change", suggest.lostFocus, false);
        Event.observe(s, "focus", suggest.focus, false);
        Event.observe(suggest.results_box, "mousemove", function(event){ suggest.updateSelection(undefined);})
        //Event.observe(suggest.suggest_box, "mouseover", function(event){ suggest.updateSelection(undefined);})
        suggest.show_page(s.value, 1);
    },
```

Comment: WOW, eh ... as said: I use jquery autocomplete ... I really do NOT want to rewrite autocomplete ;-) But nice code and a million thanks for your (very fast) answer!